# (standard_in) 1: parse error

Tags: shell-script, newlines

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 5. Write a Shell Program to Find the Area & Circumference of a Circle
echo "Enter the Radius"
read radius
arear=`echo 3.14 \* $radius \* $radius |bc`
circu=`echo 2 \* 3.14 \* $radius |bc`
echo "Area of the Circle="$arear
echo "Circumference of the Circle="$circu
```

it gives the error as below:

```
==============================================
[root@vision aiwa]#sh area.sh
Enter the Radius
9
': not a valid identifieradius
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 2: parse error
Area of the Circle =
Circumference of the Circle =
[root@vision aiwa]#
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Works for me. `Enter the Radius` `9` `Area of the Circle=254.34` `Circumference of the Circle=56.52`

Comment: what is version of your `bc`?

Comment: Try `arear='echo ...|bc'` (and corresponding for `circu`), then print the value of those variables, to see what gets fed to bc.

Comment: Tangentially related: see why [$() is preferred over backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: Typical sign of DOS line endings with spurious CR characters

Comment: Try `chmod +x /path/to/script; /path/to/script` and see the error message. Or run `bash /path/to/script | cat -A` to see the spurious CRs.